# Weird behavior UIComponents

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I'm newbie to iOS programming and I'm having a little trouble with UIComponents. I don't know why, but they aren't working properly. This images illustrates it:

[image: Some elements don't show up]

It's weird because I've just drop the elements and in some cases, I change the font but not any big deal. As you can see, my labels and the "Register" button don't show up. The worst is that the log don't say anything, so I can't know what's going on. I cleaned the project, but it doesn't work.

Any clue what's wrong? It's not the number of lines or the value of alpha, I checked that

Thanks!

Comment: Have you set constraints on the object to control their location ?

Comment: Nope, I don't set anything except font-type, just drag and drop (?).

Comment: That's why then. Set some layout constraints describing where you want everything

Comment: I'm trying, but it seems not to be working. However, how yo could explain that Placeholder values show up as text?

Comment: It's hard to guess what the code might be doing by just looking at a picture of the storyboard. Is anything happening programmatically in the AppDelegate or the LoginViewController?